# Wxpython cell access using 'a1' instead of (0,0)?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am making a GUI similar to excel.. and while writing a formula a user enters address of a cell in 'A1' format for ex- '=B1+B2' .  I want to access the cell in wxpython by 'A1' type of addressing ... Is there any inbuilt function for that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no such functionality built in to wx, so you will have to build it yourself. But it's not that hard. For most the basic version, if `cellname` is your `A1` string, it's just `row, col = int(cellname[1:]), ord(cellname[0].upper()) - 'A'`. If you want to add error handling, handling more than 26 columns, or parse complex expressions, if you understand that code, you can build on it from there.

Comment: You are a life saver. thank you very much. I ran your code and just two changes to make it work => row, col = int(cellname[1:]) - 1 , ord(cellname[0].upper()) - ord('A') .